# Why is my DbContext being disposed? How can I stop it or work around it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, xunit.net, aspnetboilerplate

I am getting an ObjectDisposedException on my dbContext object on the last line of this unit test:

```
public class InvoiceRepository_Tests : AppTestBase
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task Test_InsertAndQuery()
    {
        var invoiceRepository = Resolve<IRepository<InvoiceHistory, long>>();
        var invoice = new InvoiceHistory() { Reference = "1", Payments = new List<Payment> { new Payment() } };
        var ihId = await invoiceRepository.InsertAndGetIdAsync(invoice);
        var readInvoice = await invoiceRepository
            .Query(q => q.Where(ih => ih.Id == ihId))
            .Include(ih => ih.Payments)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
}
```

If I replace the last line with:

```
        var readInvoice = invoiceRepository.Get(ihId);
```

I don't get the error (and do get my parent record), but then I seem to have no option to populate my Payments collection.

I'm not disposing the DbContext anywhere on purpose. In fact, as far as I can tell the only place I've touched it is to add the DbSet's for these two tables and establish the HasMany relationship in OnModelCreating().

I've tried adding [UnitOfWork] to the test, which is the only suggestion I could find elsewhere, but it didn't change the behaviour.

Comment: For starters, you shouldn't be Resolving service references that way, you should be using constructor injection.  Second, You probably have the dependency injection lifestyle to transient or scoped/request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `Begin` the `UnitOfWork` explicitly:

```
[Fact]
public async Task Test_InsertAndQuery()
{
    var invoiceRepository = Resolve<IRepository<InvoiceHistory, long>>();
    var unitOfWorkManager = Resolve<IUnitOfWorkManager>();

    using (var uow = unitOfWorkManager.Begin())
    {
        var invoice = new InvoiceHistory() { Reference = "1", Payments = new List<Payment> { new Payment() } };
        var ihId = await invoiceRepository.InsertAndGetIdAsync(invoice);
        var readInvoice = await invoiceRepository
            .Query(q => q.Where(ih => ih.Id == ihId))
            .Include(ih => ih.Payments)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        // ...

        await uow.CompleteAsync();
    }
}
```

`[UnitOfWork]` attribute is not used on Test methods as the Test class may not be injected.